# "Module not found" in Ionic production build

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Whenever I perform a production build of my app, I get this error relating to my calendar module. Everything works in development serves and labs, it's only a production build that has an issue with the calendar.

Moving the contents of the src folder of the calendar directly into the src of Ionic fixes the issue - same as in this case: https://github.com/twinssbc/Ionic2-Calendar/issues/148 (scroll to the bottom) -- but that isn't a viable solution because that's just a quickfix for this particular app, I'd like to make the adjustment on my actual calendar module.

Is there a method of exporting / importing that is incorrect with the latest iterations of Ionic? I have exhausted all other avenues Googling around, I am taking a plunge at the StackOverflow ether for help.

```
[16:23:24]  copy finished in 7.66 s
Error: ./src/pages/dashboard/dashboard.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../node_modules/ionic3-calendar-en/src/calendar/calendar.ngfactory' in '/Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/ionic/xxx/src/pages/dashboard' resolve '../../../node_modules/ionic3-calendar-en/src/calendar/calendar.ngfactory' in '/Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/ionic/xxx/src/pages/dashboard' using description file: /Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/ionic/xxx/package.json (relative path: ./src/pages/dashboard)
Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
```

This is the module in question:
https://github.com/gbrits/ionic-calendar

Notice there are others encountering the same issue relating to this module:
https://github.com/gbrits/ionic-calendar/issues/8

Please feel free to submit a pull request if you know the fix.

My thoughts are it's something related to relative paths?

Comment: did you found any solution to this? I think I may have the same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60077380/how-to-fix-missing-module-not-found-build-error-in-ionic-3-application