# How to fix missing 'module not found' build error in Ionic 3 application

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I can't build Ionic 3 app for production with

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

Error received

```
[14:06:47]  ionic-app-script task: "build" 
[14:06:47]  Error: ./src/pages/dashboard/dashboard.ngfactory.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 
            '../../../node_modules/ionic3-calendar-en/src/calendar/calendar.ngfactory' in 
            'C:\repo\iota-mobile\src\pages\dashboard' resolve 
            '../../../node_modules/ionic3-calendar-en/src/calendar/calendar.ngfactory' in 
            'C:\repo\iota-mobile\src\pages\dashboard' using description file: C:\repo\iota-mobile\package.json (relative 
            path: ./src/pages/dashboard) Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration after using 
            description file: C:\repo\iota-mobile\package.json (relative path: ./src/pages/dashboard) using description 
            file: C:\repo\iota-mobile\node_modules\ionic3-calendar-en\package.json (relative path: 
            ./src/calendar/calendar.ngfactory) no extension Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration 
            C:\repo\iota-mobile\node_modules\ionic3-calendar-en\src\calendar\calendar.ngfactory doesn't exist .ts Field 
            'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration 
            C:\repo\iota-mobile\node_modules\ionic3-calendar-en\src\calendar\calendar.ngfactory.ts doesn't exist .js 
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration 
            C:\repo\iota-mobile\node_modules\ionic3-calendar-en\src\calendar\calendar.ngfactory.js doesn't exist .json 
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
```

However, clearly there is some issue with AOT and ioinc3-calender library since app is working with ng serve and I can build app debug version. Typescript used is 2.6.2. Angular is 5.2. Library is imported in module as:

```
import {CalendarModule} from "ionic3-calendar-en";
```

I tried to downgrade typescript version to 2.4.2 build succeeded but then apk is not running on phone.

Index.html

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="" version="1.0.6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>TestMobile</name>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="WKPort" value="12345" />

    <allow-navigation href="http://localhost:12345/*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
        <config-file parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>You can take photos</string>
        </config-file>
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^2.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-version" spec="0.1.9" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid" spec="~1.3.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="4.0.3" />
    <engine name="browser" spec="5.0.4" />
    <engine name="android" spec="^7.1.4" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="5.0.0" />
</widget>
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "test-mobile",
    "version": "1.0.5",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
        "@ionic-native/app-version": "^4.0.0",
        "@ionic-native/camera": "4.20.0",
        "@ionic-native/core": "^4.15.0",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.15.0",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^4.15.0",
        "@ionic-native/unique-device-id": "^4.20.0",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
        "@types/node": "^10.12.0",
        "angular-svg-round-progressbar": "^2.0.0",
        "aws-amplify": "^1.1.7",
        "aws-amplify-angular": "^2.0.10",
        "cordova-android": "7.1.4",
        "cordova-browser": "5.0.4",
        "cordova-ios": "5.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
        "cordova-plugin-camera": "4.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.4.0",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
        "ionic-angular": "^3.9.2",
        "ionic-long-press": "^1.5.0",
        "ionic3-calendar-en": "^1.1.3",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "moment": "^2.22.2",
        "rxjs": "5.5.11",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.26"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.3",
        "@ionic/lab": "1.0.11",
        "typescript": "~2.6.2"
    },
    "description": "An Ionic project",
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
                "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
            "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
            "cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid": {},
            "cordova-plugin-camera": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
            "browser",
            "android",
            "ios"
        ]
    }
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: Can you show your index.html and package.json file?

Comment: @StephenRomero sure, I updated my question with index.html and package.json

Comment: Thanks, so is the calendar plugin imported in your app module or do you have a sub module that it is imported in?

Comment: It's imported in two sub modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary solution is to build project without prod flag.

```
ionic cordova build android --release
```

Downside is that build(apk) is 3 times bigger then with prod flag.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading the typescript version to "typescript": "~2.4.2"
run npm i --save then rebuild

Comment: I already tried that I wrote in my question. If I downgrade I can build in production mode but then app is not working... I am getting white screen

Comment: you need to debug it in chrom to see the error using the remote device tool

Comment: there are no errors in debug version, in chrome or on device... I think this is because I only receive error when using --prod flag